# Create TF records----ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, modulenotfounderror

!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}

!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}

**i'm tring to run this code but its showing error**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 25, in 
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 25, in 
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

what should i do??

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you can see your post has formatting issues, please reformat your post. Your error message says `No module named 'tensorflow'`. So, install the module using pip: `pip install tensorflow`

Comment: i had already installed tensorflow using pip command. But still the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Do you alredy install package? Try on terminal:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.4.1 --ignore-installed
```

Comment: tensorflow is already installed. Facing the same error.